# Cookies in header but not received on back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, next.js

To keep it simple I have a Node.js/express PORT:3001 API and a nextjs front-end PORT:3000, everything seems to be working fine until I decided to use cookies to store the JWT and then to send it back to the API with every request.

When a user logs in from the browser, I have this (on express) for the cookie:

```js
      res.cookie("JWT_TOKEN", token, {
        maxAge: 7000 * 40 *60*60, // just for testing
        httpOnly: false,
        domain: 'localhost',
        path: '/',
        signed: false,
        secure: false,
      });
```

And on the browser the cookie gets set.

But I have absolutely no luck in receiving the cookie back, I can see it in the headers but not in express.

This is on the nextjs part:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const {
    query: { page = 1 },
  } = ctx;
  console.log(ctx.req.headers);
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:3001/api/movies?page=${page}`,
      { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer test" } },
      { withCredentials: true }
    );
    return {
      props: data,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
}
```

So that ctx.req.headers has the cookie in it

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
  accept: '*/*',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/movies',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,it-IT;q=0.8,it;q=0.7',
  cookie: 'JWT_TOKEN=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjIsInJvbGUiOiJ1c2VyIiwiaWF0IjoxNjA4ODk5Njg4fQ.9b9Nl5FWynXa38o-VJyT_B8vBeSk6WyBoPeuv_6GLSo'
}
```

But on the server, using cookie parser I get back: (logging the cookie and req.headers)

```
[Object: null prototype] {}
{
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  authorization: 'Bearer asd',
  'user-agent': 'axios/0.21.0',
  host: 'localhost:3001',
  connection: 'close'
}
```

Finally I tried from postman to set some cookies and it works!

```
{
  POSTMAN: 'ALL_GOOD',
  JWT_TOKEN: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjIsInJvbGUiOiJ1c2VyIiwiaWF0IjoxNjA4OTAwMzE2fQ.56DBF0xw2_dHy16dANwQlIkuX_zhUZMaTcDqLv7kyv4'
}
{
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.8',
  accept: '*/*',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'postman-token': '0cea19b2-16a0-46f2-a311-d4d28f04d42a',
  host: 'localhost:3001',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  cookie: 'POSTMAN=ALL_GOOD; JWT_TOKEN=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjIsInJvbGUiOiJ1c2VyIiwiaWF0IjoxNjA4OTAwMzE2fQ.56DBF0xw2_dHy16dANwQlIkuX_zhUZMaTcDqLv7kyv4'
}
```

So either I'm doing something wrong, which is more than likely since I'm confused a bit authentication and authorization, or I'm missing something about how nextjs works. One thing I've noticed is the URL in the network tab, the request is going to

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/_next/data/development/movies.json
```

instead of http://localhost:3001/api/movies

But apart from that I'm lost.

I could do something like this

```js
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:3001/api/movies?page=${page}`,
      { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${ctx.req.headers.cookie}`, cookie:  ctx.req.headers.cookie} },
      { withCredentials: true }
    );
```

And now I do have access to it on express, but for reason it seems wrong, since the cookie IS already in the headers.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using cookie-parser?

```
var express = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())
```

Then you can use

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies)
})
```

Comment: Hey, yeah that's what I'm using, but I was saying that no matter what I can see the cookies from NextJS.

Answer (score -2):

Cookies are only available locally on the users computer. You cannot extract their cookies via your backend. You need a database and that would mean that you cannot use cookies for storage. Use the google firebase as it is very simple to record data. In that way, you would not have to use long back-end algorithms!

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, cookies are sent back and forth, they are meant to have some sort of state.